# CakePHP 2.x: Missing Plugin Exception while installing on shared host

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have been having an issue that has been driving me nuts all day.

I have a cakePhp site working with no problems on my local machine, another developers local machine and a dedicated server (for the production environment).  I copied the development installation to a shared host (justhost.com).  When I copied the site over (using rsync) to the shared host, I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MissingPluginException' with message 'Plugin TinyMce could not be found.' in /home4/ncreport/public_html/mars/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php:97 Stack trace: #0 /home4/ncreport/public_html/mars/app/Config/bootstrap.php(71): CakePlugin::load('TinyMce') #1 /home4/ncreport/public_html/mars/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(81): include('/home4/ncreport...') #2 /home4/ncreport/public_html/mars/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(138): Configure::bootstrap(true) #3 /home4/ncreport/public_html/mars/app/webroot/index.php(77): include('/home4/ncreport...') #4 {main} thrown in /home4/ncreport/public_html/mars/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php on line 97
>   <

I have tried multiple things found in google searches to remedy the problem.  No luck.  I have tried to change the .htaccess file to add a rewrite base, tried to specify the fully qualified plugin path in the bootstrap file, tried to delete everything and reinstall the entire app, tried to change the document root to several different values, tried everything I could think of....  It appears to be an issue with the shared host, but I am unable to determine the cause.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- it turns out that on the current installation the names for the plugins is case sensitive.  The installation where this was copied from does not have case sensitivity.

Corrected the case on the load statement and everything worked well.